# Como aumentar a fonte do Grid View Result no SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Quero aumentar a fonte do Grid View Result porque fica muito pequena em um notebook full hd de 15,6.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fui nas opções de Fonts and Colors mas não encontro a opção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para aumentar o tamanho do Grid View Result vá em Ferramentas -> Opções ira abrir uma janela. 
Siga os seguintes passos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1 AMBIENTE -> 2 FONTES E CORES -> 3 BUSQUE POR "RESULTADOS DA GRADE" -> 4 MODIFIQUE O TAMANHO.
Feche e abra o SSMS